# Issue with Arduino/Thingspeak

Tags: python, arduino, iot

I'm trying to upload sound sensor data to Thingspeak. Having problems getting the data when connected to the Wifi.

The Arduino is supposed to pick up sound, light up an LED and send the data to the Thingspeak but the LED isn't responding once the code for Thingspeak is input and it's not sending any data to Thingspeak.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "ThingSpeak.h"
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFi101.h>

// Create instance of WiFi client
WiFiClient client;
char ssid[] = "Arduino";        //  your network SSID (name) 

// Add yourThingSpeak channel information here
unsigned long myChannelNumber = 365995;
const char * myWriteAPIKey = "30Y94U59QGRL5OEJ";



const int ledPin = 6; //pin 13 built-in led
const int soundPin = A0; //sound sensor attach to A0
int threshold = 1000; //Set minimum threshold for LED lit
void setup()
{
  pinMode(ledPin,OUTPUT);//set pin13 as OUTPUT
  Serial.begin(9600); //initialize serial
  ThingSpeak.begin(client);
    WiFi.begin(ssid);
    // Print WiFi strength information
  printCurrentNet();
}
void loop()
{


  int value = analogRead(soundPin);//read the value of A0
  Serial.println(value);//print the value
  if(value > threshold) //if the value is greater than 600
  {

    digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);//turn off the led
    //delay(1000);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);//turn on the led
    ThingSpeak.setField(1, value);


  }

}
void printCurrentNet() {
  // Print the WiFi signal strength:
  long rssi = WiFi.RSSI();
  Serial.print("Signal strength (RSSI): ");
  Serial.print(rssi);
  Serial.println(" dBm");
}
```

Comment: The first thing I would do is to try and narrow down if this is an issue with your code OR an issue with the wiring and hardware. Did you triple check your wiring to make sure it is correct? GPIO numbers are correct? you can also run pintest to see if there are any issues (note: I use RaspberryPi so I'm not entirely familiar with Auduino)

Comment: I had the Mic and the LED set up and working fine, it responded just as intended until the thingspeak code started getting added. I've slowly went through it but truthfully I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: I would try to add some debugging code in to print out the values of "value" and "threshold". You can also try commenting out most of your code and just try "digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);//turn on the led" to make sure you can atleast turn on the LED via code and your setup. If the issue is truly code/logic related, your issue is the if statement for value > threshold

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why the LED don't light up maybe there are some problems with the data or with wiring also always add some debugging prints using the serial monitor.

Also why don't try to set the threshold to 600 instead of 1000

```
int threshold = 600; //Set minimum threshold for LED lit
```

Also don't forget to update ThingSpeak channel

```
digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);//turn on the led
ThingSpeak.setField(1, value);
ThingSpeak.writeFields(myChannelNumber, myWriteAPIKey);
```